# Firebase cloud function: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to download an image from an url and then uploading it to my firebase cloud storage.
This is the code i'm using.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';    
const download = require('image-downloader');
const tmp = require('tmp');

export const downloadFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
        var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();


      await  tmp.dir(async function _tempDirCreated(err: any, path: any) {
          if (err) throw err;

          const options = {
            url: 'theUrlIWantToPutInTheStorage',
            dest: path,
          }
          console.log('Dir: ', path);

          await download.image(options)
          .then(async () => {
            console.log('Saved');

            await bucket.upload(path, {
              destination: "testfolder/test.jpg",
              metadata: "metadata",
            });

          })
          .catch((err2: any) => console.error(err2))


        });


      });
```

But from the firebase console (logs) I get this error:

```
    { Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read errno: -21, code: 'EISDIR', syscall: 'read' }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this console.log('Saved') appearing in the log?

Comment: Is the "testfolder/test.jpg" a directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `path` that you provide to the method `upload` should be a file and not a directory.

> `upload(pathString, optionsopt, callbackopt) → {Promise.<UploadResponse>}`
>
> Upload a file to the bucket. This is a convenience method that wraps `File#createWriteStream`.

Example :

```
const options = {
  destination: 'new-image.png',
  resumable: true,
  validation: 'crc32c',
  metadata: {
    metadata: {
      event: 'Fall trip to the zoo'
    }
  }
};

bucket.upload('local-image.png', options, function(err, file) {
  // Your bucket now contains:
  // - "new-image.png" (with the contents of `local-image.png')

  // `file` is an instance of a File object that refers to your new file.
});
```

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html